# Concentration bounds on a sequence of (0,1)-experiments

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

I have a $(0,1)$-experiment that returns $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$
with probability $1-p$. Let $X_i$ be the random variable describing
the outcome of iteration $i$ of the experiment. I'm interested in the
value $Y_t=\sum_{i=0}^t X_i$, which counts the number of successes
since the beginning of the sequence. The sequence terminates as soon
as $Y_t \geq (p+\delta) \cdot t$ (with $0 < \delta < 1-p$) is
fulfilled, i.e., when the ratio between $0$ and $1$ is over the threshold
$p+\delta$.

Quite intuitively the sum will converge to $Y_t = p\cdot t$ (expected
value) but the probability of reaching $Y_t = (p+\delta)\cdot t$ is
non-zero, and will be reached in an infinite run. The question is
when will it be reached?

For this there are two interesting values I'd like to calculate: the
probability of each step $t \rightarrow t+1$ being the last, i.e.,
$Pr[Y_{t+1} \geq (p+\delta) \cdot (t+1)|Y_t < (p+\delta) \cdot t]$ and
the expected time until the sequence is terminated, $\mathrm{E}[\text{steps}]$.

Comment: Will the sequence stop immediately if $X_0=1$, or are you interested in asymptotic behavior? Also, the probability of exceeding $(p+\delta)t$ will depend on $t$, so it is not obvious that it has to be reached, especially that it has to be reached with a finite expected time.

Comment: I'm interested in the expected time until the first event $X_i=1$ so it would indeed stop at $X_0=1$. A variant, which is actually more interesting, would be to have a prefix of length $w$ in which no 1 may occur, but I thought I'd start by asking the generic case and try to work out the prefixed case myself. All the better if the probability does not approach 1 for arbitrary large $t$ since I want to find an upper bound on something bad happening :-)

Comment: [Very closely related](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/64499/2970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the question's queries is the probability that "the next step will be the last". The OP states this probability as $Pr[Y_{t+1} \geq (p+\delta) \cdot (t+1)|Y_t < (p+\delta) \cdot t]$, but this is not a correct representation. And this is because we require that the process must stop *the first time* it reaches the relevant threshold. Left unstopped, the process may cross the threshold at time $t$,then fall below the threshold that holds for period $t+1$, and then cross the next threshold again, etc. Namely we may have $Y_t < (p+\delta) \cdot t$, but $Y_{t-1} > (p+\delta) \cdot (t-1)$,  in which case $Y_t$ (and of course $Y_{t+1}$) won't be observed since that process will have stopped at $Y_{t-1}$.

To compact notation, denote $h_t$ the threshold of step $t$. Then the appropriate statement of the required probability is

$$ Pr[Y_{t+1} \geq h_{t+1}\mid Y_{t+1}\; \text{is observed}]\equiv P^s_{t+1} $$

So first we need to calculate the *continuation probability* of the process. 
Counting from $1$, the probability that $Y_2$ will be observed is equal to the probability that at the first step, the Bernoulli trial will give a zero value: $Pr[Y_{2} \;\text{is observed}] = Pr(Y_1 =0) =1-p$.
The probability that $Y_3$ is observed is equal to the probability that $Y_2$ does not reach or exceed $h_2$, *given* that $Y_2$ is observed.

$$P^c_3 \equiv Pr[Y_3 \;\text{is observed}] = Pr[Y_2 < h_2 \mid Y_2 \;\text{is observed}]$$

Applying Bayes' theorem, we have

$$Pr[Y_2 < h_2 \mid Y_2 \;\text{is observed}] = Pr[Y_2 \;\text{is observed} \mid Y_2 < h_2 ]\frac {Pr[Y_2 < h_2]}{Pr[Y_2 \;\text{is observed}]}$$

$$=1\cdot\frac {Pr[Y_2 < h_2]}{Pr[Y_2 \;\text{is observed}]} \Rightarrow P^c_3 = Pr[Y_2 < h_2]\cdot \left(P^c_2\right)^{-1}$$

So the probability that the $t+1$ step will be the last is
$$P^s_{t+1} = Pr[Y_{t+1}\; \text{is observed}\mid Y_{t+1} \geq h_{t+1}] \frac {Pr[Y_{t+1} \geq h_{t+1}]}{Pr[Y_{t+1}\; \text{is observed}]}$$
$$= Pr[Y_{t+1} \geq h_{t+1}]\cdot \left(P^c_{t+1}\right)^{-1}$$

Denote for compactness the unconditional probability of *not* reaching the threshold at trial $t$, $P^b_t$. These are probabilities regardless of whether the process may have crossed the threshold at some step before $t$. Then, using the recursive formula for $P^c_{t+1}$ we obtain

$$P^s_{t+1} = (1-P^b_{t+1})\frac{P^b_{t-1}\cdot P^b_{t-3}\cdot...}{P^b_{t}\cdot P^b_{t-2}\cdot...} \qquad [1]$$

Equation $[1]$ contains unconditional probabilites of sums (of different cardinality) of i.i.d. Bernoulli variables. The probability generating function of a Bernoulli r.v. is $G(z) = 1-p +pz$. The pgf of the sum of i.i.d Bernoullis is just the product of the individual pgf's. So

$$G_{Y}(z;t) = (1-p+pz)^t$$
The probability of $Y_t$ having the integer value $0\le k\le t$ (its pmf, that is) is recovered through the $k$-th derivative of the pgf evaluated at zero
$$P(Y_t=k) = \frac {1}{k!}G^{(k)}_{Y}(0;t) = \left(\begin{matrix} t \\k  
\end{matrix}\right) (1-p)^{t-k}p^k$$

and so

$$P(Y_t\le k) = \sum_{j=0}^k \left(\begin{matrix} t \\j  
\end{matrix}\right) (1-p)^{t-j}p^j$$

In our case the threshold $h_t$ is not, in general, an integer. In order to cover both the integer and non-integer case, we use the ceiling function of $h_t-1$,  $\lceil h_t-1 \rceil$, obtaining for example,

$$P^b_{t} = Pr[Y_{t} \le \lceil h_t-1 \rceil] =  \sum_{j=0}^{\lceil h_t-1 \rceil} \left(\begin{matrix} t \\j  
\end{matrix}\right) (1-p)^{t-j}p^j \qquad [2]$$

a formula through which we can obtain the various components of $[1]$, for each step, and be able to calculate the required probability $P^s_{t+1}$ for any $\{p,\delta, t\}$.

Answer (score 6):

The expected time until the sequence is terminates is infinite.  In fact, not only is the expected value of $\text{min}\{t : Y_t>(p+\delta)t\}$ infinite for any $\delta>0$, but even the expected value of $\text{min}\{t : Y_t > pt + \delta\}$ is infinite.

This can be proven using the [optional sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) (also known as optional stopping theorem).  Define $\tau = \text{min}\{t : Y_t > pt + \delta\}$, and define $Z_t=Y_t-pt$.  Note that

1. $Z_t$ is a martingale, and
2. By definition, $Z_\tau\geq\delta>0$ and therefore $E[Z_\tau]>0$.

If $E[\tau]<\infty$ then the optional sampling theorem would imply that $E[Z_\tau]=Z_0=0$, which is a contradiction.

The situation for the random time you mention in the OP is even more severe.
Let $K_t$ denote the event $Y_t>(p+\delta)t$ and define $\sigma=\text{min}\{t : K_t\}$. It can be shown that $P[\sigma=\infty]>0$, meaning that this threshold might never be crossed.

Briefly, again we can do this by contradiction.  First, assume $P[\sigma<\infty]=1$, and let $\sigma_2$ denote the second time that 
$K_t$ occurs.

Note that, for any $t$, if $Y_t-Y_\sigma>(p+\delta)(t-\sigma)$, then, since $Y_\sigma>(p+\delta)\sigma$ by assumption, it must be the case that $Y_t>(p+\delta)t$.  So, by the independence of the $Y_t$, it follows that
$P[\sigma_2-\sigma_1<\infty]=1$ and thus $P[\sigma_2<\infty]=1$ also.  And the same goes for $\sigma_3$ and $\sigma_4$, and so on, which means that the event $K_t$ occurs infinitely often with probability $1$.

However, since each $Y_t$ is the sum of independent Bernoulli trials, then it can be shown (i.e. [Chernoff bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound)) that there exists a fixed constant $C$ (depending on the constants $p$ and $\delta$) such that 
$$P[K_t]=P[Y_t-pt>\delta t]<e^{-Ct}.$$
From this it follows that
$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty P[K_t]<\infty,$$
and thus by the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma), with probability $1$, $K_t$ only occurs finitely often.  Hence we have a contradiction.

As for calculating the probabilities that each step is the last (i.e. the probabilities $P[\sigma=t]$), I can't think of any easy way to do this without doing a simulation.  That doesn't mean that there isn't any way to do it, of course.

If you are looking for more information related to this question, I would suggest looking into the continuous version of the process, which would be brownian motion with drift.  I imagine you can find somewhere a calculation of the probability that brownian motion with drift crosses this kind of a threshold.

To add: if you are interested in numerical values, they are pretty easy to compute, at least for moderate values of $T$.  Here is a simple R function that computes the probability of escape, as well as the conditional distribution conditional on survival up to time n:

```
simProb<-function(p,n,delta){
  pp<-c(p,1-p)
  thresh<- floor(1+(p+delta)*(1:n))
  x<-1
  res<-rep(0,n)
  rsum<-1
  for(i in 1:n){
    x<-convolve(x,pp,t="o")
    if(length(x)>thresh[i]){      
      res[i]<-sum(x[(thresh[i]+1):length(x)])*rsum
      rsum<-rsum-res[i]
      x<-x[1:(thresh[i])]
      x<-x/sum(x)
    }
  }
  list(p=res,x=x)
}
```

Here is what the survival probabilities are for some specific constants:

```
plot(1-cumsum(simProb(0.6,1000,0.01)$p),type="l",ylim=c(0,0.4))
```

[image]

You can also examine the survival probability as a function of $\delta$ like this:

```
delt<-0.001*(1:399)
surv<-sapply(delt,  function(delta)1-sum(simProb(0.6,1000,delta)$p))
plot(delt,surv,type='l')
```

[image]

You can see how discontinuous this is: the reason is that, since $Y_t$ and $t$ are integer-valued the exit condition $Y_t>(p+\delta)t$ is effectively discontinuous as a function of $t$.  For this reason, it is unlikely that there is a clean formula for the probability of survival up to time $t$.

Comment: (+1) This looks right. Nice answer. You're providing good, high-quality content. Cheers. :-)

Comment: There is a mention of brownian motion with drift as a related concept. We know that for brownian motion, $\lim\sup_{t \rightarrow \infty} B(t) = \infty$ (or, $\tau = \inf\{t: B(t) \geq \delta\} < \infty$ a.s). How is this different from our discrete setting?

Comment: The limit theorems will be pretty much the same for BM: if  $\tau = \inf\{t:B(t)=\delta\}$ then $E[\tau]=\infty$, and if $\tau=\inf\{t:B(t)+\delta t+\epsilon\}$ then $P[\tau=\infty]>0$.  However, with Brownian motion, in some cases possible to derive explicit formulas for crossing times and probabilities, whereas in the discrete setting this is typically more difficult.